# Possible to populate $templateCache before defining routes?

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I don't wish to lazy load my route templates. Instead I want to load all my route templates into $templateCache ahead of any routes executing.

This is what I am doing:

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']).config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider)
{
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);

    $routeProvider.when("/main", {templateUrl: "main", controller: "MainCtrl"})
                  .when("/login",{templateUrl: "login", controller: "LoginCtrl"});
}])
.run(['$location','$templateCache', function ($location, $templateCache)
{
   //...Save templates in $templateCache
   $location.path("/login");
}]);
```

This works OK if you browse to `/` because it doesn't match any route. But if you browse or refresh on `/#/login` it seems the route service attempts to load the template before my run block gets to run and makes a request to the server for it.

Is there anyway to ensure the code that populates the $templateCache will execute before the route service goes looking for the template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use grunt you I highly recommend [grunt-angular-templates](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates) for that purpose, but if you don't and want to do this manually create separate module in which you have similar logic to what you have right now, something along the lines:

```
angular.module('myapp.templates').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
$templateCache.put(...
```

and then simply reference that module as your app dependency. Run block of dependency module will run first before routing logic kicks in and it's what you want.

Comment: That's a good idea. I thought it would work, but it didn't. The *config* block of the main module 'myApp' runs before the *run* block of the 'templates' module even though myApp has a dependency on templates. I'm thinking config blocks don't have to wait on dependencies to execute like run blocks likely do. And unfortunately the routes need to be setup in a config block.

Comment: Yeah, routes need to be set up in config block, but routing itself doesn't run in config block, so code I attached will do the trick, $templateCache will be populated ahead of redirect. I do this in my apps (using grunt-angular-templates) and it works perfectly.

Comment: @Tadeusz No, check your network traffic. Routing will attempt to download the template for the route matching the current URL even before the run blocks execute. (1.2-rc3) You may not notice this if your server is able to respond correctly to this request. Future route changes will use the cache, but the initial one will not.

Comment: @user169867 I've checked it few times and there weren't any requests to server for template(disabled caching etc). Did you try to have run block where you load templates in separate module?

Comment: @Tadeusz Yes, though I do need to request the templates from the server using $http. I think you're doing it all inline, that could be why.

Comment: @user169867 yes, that must be it. I include compiled to js templates in my main js file. Not sure about your case, maybe route resolve property would do the trick (add $http request as route dependency so it would wait till $http requests is resolved)?

Comment: @user169867: I had the same async problem. I got it to work using Taduesz's suggestion but 1st I loaded the templates using jQuery and after they were available I manually bootstrapped the angular app. That way I had the templates available to add to the cache in the run block and didn't need to make any async calls. And that worked :)

Comment: +1, considering the comment thread (suggestion: include information from comments in the answer)